# VSFTPD problem on Centos 5.4 with different port

Tags: linux, port, centos5, ftp

I'm changing over my server to operate ftp on different ports than standard 20/21 accomodate a nas on the same network.  I have changed the ports to 201/202 but cannot connect locally from a pc on the same network.  If I try to connect to port 21, the server refuses connection, but on 202 it just times out.  I can connect on the linux server using "ftp localhost 202".  Its a CentOS 5.4 running vsftpd

I'm a bit baffled as to what I'm missing -  hopefully someone can help me :)

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Are you running a firewall?  (iptables?)

Comment: and now I feel like an idiot!  I checked the firewall on the client pc and on the router but not on the server! 

Added the rules for the two ports and now am in business. Thanks mate - I owe you a pint!

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to confirm that the vsftpd is running on the expected ports?
Running /bin/netstat -lntp as root will give you a listing of what programs are runing on what tcp ports.

If it does appear to be listening as expected you can try and connect by running /usr/bin/ftp
and then typing 'open localhost 202' at the ftp> prompt.

hth,
mc

Comment: Hi Martin,I ran netstat and everything seems to be running as expected. local address was 0.0.0.0:202 though, is this correct?
I also ran ftp 'open localhost 202' and connected ok.